# java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface com.google.android.gms.location.SettingsClient, but class was expected

Tags: android, react-native, expo

i am currently using expo-location to get the users current position. The IOS build works without any problem but in the android build getting the current position does not work.

Here is the Error Message i get:

```
2023-10-22 13:42:16.645 20479-20563/? W/System.err: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
2023-10-22 13:42:16.645 20479-20563/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2023-10-22 13:42:16.645 20479-20563/? W/System.err:     at expo.modules.core.ExportedModule.invokeExportedMethod(ExportedModule.java:98)
2023-10-22 13:42:16.645 20479-20563/? W/System.err:     at expo.modules.adapters.react.NativeModulesProxy.callMethod(NativeModulesProxy.java:166)
2023-10-22 13:42:16.645 20479-20563/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2023-10-22 13:42:16.645 20479-20563/? W/System.err:     at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)
2023-10-22 13:42:16.645 20479-20563/? W/System.err:     at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:188)
2023-10-22 13:42:16.645 20479-20563/? W/System.err:     at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
2023-10-22 13:42:16.645 20479-20563/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
2023-10-22 13:42:16.645 20479-20563/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
2023-10-22 13:42:16.645 20479-20563/? W/System.err:     at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:27)
2023-10-22 13:42:16.645 20479-20563/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
2023-10-22 13:42:16.645 20479-20563/? W/System.err:     at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:228)
2023-10-22 13:42:16.645 20479-20563/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
2023-10-22 13:42:16.645 20479-20563/? W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface com.google.android.gms.location.SettingsClient, but class was expected (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.location.SettingsClient' appears in base.apk!classes2.dex)
2023-10-22 13:42:16.645 20479-20563/? W/System.err:     at expo.modules.location.LocationModule.resolveUserSettingsForRequest(LocationModule.java:653)
2023-10-22 13:42:16.645 20479-20563/? W/System.err:     at expo.modules.location.LocationModule.addPendingLocationRequest(LocationModule.java:635)
2023-10-22 13:42:16.645 20479-20563/? W/System.err:     at expo.modules.location.LocationModule.getCurrentPositionAsync(LocationModule.java:291)
2023-10-22 13:42:16.645 20479-20563/? W/System.err:     ... 13 more
```

I am using Expo Managed Project